# Why is my 5GB file splitting into the same file when I use -split on Mac?

Tags: unix

I am trying to use the `split -l 100000 file.txt` command on my Mac but all it does it create the file called xab and the size remains the same. I ask, where are the chunks?

Comment: How many lines is file.txt?  You can check this with `wc -l file.txt`

Comment: Oh, and what is your desired behavior?  'Chunks of *size N*' or '*N chunks*'?

Comment: I tried running wc -l file.txt, returns 0 file.txt. I want to split the file into say 1gb chunks. But I want to ensure the lines are not cut or anything.

Comment: I have an answer for you.  Typing it now.

Comment: I have the exact same file type, just 69mb, the split command works on that one with relative ease. Creates problems for only this 5GB file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely have a file called 'xaa' in the directory as well.

Your result is because `split` works on newline characters and there may not be a newline in that text file.  You should also check that the file.txt is what you expect and is not empty by checking its size with `du` or the top lines with `head`.

Say for instance a 12 line file:

```
drop.local]➜  split_demo  wc -l requirements.txt
      12 requirements.txt
```

Which I then split into *however many* files are required so that each is 2 lines long:

```
drop.local]➜  split_demo  split -l 2 requirements.txt
```

Resulting in 6 files of 2 length, which makes sense:

```
drop.local]➜  split_demo  ls
requirements.txt xab              xad              xaf
xaa              xac              xae
drop.local]➜  split_demo  cat xaa
pip install flask==0.9
pip install flask-login
```

Now let's say that I have a binary file:

```
drop.local]➜  split_demo  dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/split_demo/block_file bs=1m count=5
5+0 records in
5+0 records out
5242880 bytes transferred in 0.649609 secs (8070823 bytes/sec)
drop.local]➜  split_demo  du -h block_file
5.0M    block_file
drop.local]➜  split_demo  file block_file
block_file: data
```

Newlines don't make a lot of sense here, so let's chunk it into 1 megabyte blocks:

```
drop.local]➜  split_demo  split -b 1m block_file
drop.local]➜  split_demo  ls
block_file xaa        xab        xac        xad        xae
```

In your case, you want to use blocks to get your 1024m chunks.

Comment: I don't get it. It obviously has lines. I just used Hexfiend and everything seems normal to me?

Comment: `wc -l` counts the lines in the file, so something isn't adding up here.  Can you upload file.txt?

Comment: The file is 5GB. It's on a file sharing site, 600zip, expands into 5.6 GB to be precise. It's strange isn't it.

Comment: Is it actually a text file? Please paste the output of `file file.txt`

Comment: ASCII English text, with very long lines, with no line terminators

Comment: "text...*with no line terminators*" there's your answer -- splitting on lines won't work for this file.  use the block syntax from above to split the file into 1GB chunks (e.g. split -b 1024m file.txt)

Comment: I see, that's interesting. So is there a way to make sure that this 5GB file has lines in the first place because I need data processing in a read-line fashion?

Comment: If you're not generating the file, you'd need to split it on some known value,  Check out `man split` for a description of the 'pattern' option, but that will only be helpful if there's a predictable set of characters to denote the start of each line.

Comment: This is where a line starts from: {"created any help would be appreciated :) Thanks tristan.

Comment: I think this comment section has gone out of scope as the `split` behavior has been explained.  Please open a different question with a couple of example lines asking how to use regex to split lines in a file and accept my answer.

Comment: So it seems all of the 5GB data is on 1 line, I need to turn it into lines, it's JSON so each line starts from {"created   ....how would I do that. I think I need to convert the file into lines first